# CSS wordpress footer widgets stack when page is re-sized

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am Using Wordpress, Twenty Eleven child theme.

I had an issue where all my divs moved when I re sized the page. After persevering I managed to work it out by adding a wrapper around my body html mark up. This stopped all the divs moving when the page was re sized.

```
#site-wrapper{margin: auto; margin: auto; width: 1000px;}
```

However I have added five widget areas which run across my footer

One     |         two   |         three    |       four     |      five

But when the page is re sized the widget areas stack on top of each other

One

Two

Three

Four

Five

Everything else renders correctly.
I have tried adding a wrapper round the footer with { margin: auto; margin: auto; width: 1000px; }, this did not work widgets still stack
I have also tried positioning relative / absolute to the widget items themselves, and the wrapper without success. I think it has got something to do with

```
    float: left;
```

on the widget items but I cannot see a way round this? Hope someone can guide me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance, my CSS below for the widget item is below

```
/* Footer Widget Areas */
#supplementary {
border-top: none;
width: 80%;
padding: 1.625em 7.6%;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Three Footer Widget Areas */
#supplementary.two .widget-area {
float: left;
margin-right: 2.7%;
width: 17.78%;
}
#supplementary.two .widget-area + .widget-area {
margin-right: 0;
}

/* Three Footer Widget Areas */
#supplementary.three .widget-area {
float: left;
margin-right: 2.7%;
width: 22.18%;
}
#supplementary.three .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area {
margin-right: 0;
}

#supplementary.four .widget-area{
float: left;
margin-right: 3.7%;
width: 22.18%;
}

#supplementary.four .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area {
margin-right: 0;
}

#supplementary.five .widget-area{
float: left;
margin-right: 2.9%;
width: 16.7%;
}

#supplementary.five .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area +   .widget-area+ .widget-area{
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hope someone can advise I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is by **design**. WordPress 2011 is a [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) theme intended to look good on any size device. Smaller devices do not have space to render widgets alongside the main content so this theme, along with most other responsive themes, moves them below the main content on small screens.

Overriding this functionality seems incredibly counter-intuitive. If you really don't want a responsive design (and in this day in age, you should want one) then you should probably opt for a parent theme that is not responsive.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response much appreciated. I understand this is by design but this is a requirement that has been requested. They want something like the footer widgets on this site respond when re sized: http://www.stylemepretty.com/

Comment: I have the page looking great on ipad, iphone and samsung galaxy s2 (portrait and lanscape using media) this problem of the widgets stacking is purely related to desktop browsers

Comment: Seeing the site in action would be helpful... Do you have it live somewhere?

Comment: I have it on a test sub domain which I don't want to be indexed at the moment but the footer widgets are the same as on this site stylemepretty.com when the page is resized the stay fixed, on mine the stack to the left! Thanks for you help much appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing what you're seeing, it's hard to say, but with their implementation they have the same styling for each of the 5 widgets across. Yours all vary and so you may be running into issues there. They're also using static widths, you're using %s. Any one of those could be to blame, but CSS cascades, so just seeing what you have in your question isn't really enough.

Comment: Ok! so do you suggest using pixels instead of percentages for my widget widths? is that what you mean by static widths? thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm simply noting the differences between your code and theirs. %s wouldn't inherently cause a problem, but it's easier to get your math wrong that way. Why are all the widgets different margins & widths though? That's more interesting than using % widths.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, if my padding / borders and width add up to the container width in percentages then the widgets will not stack? or am I off the mark?

Comment: Yes. Basically. Your CSS seems more complex than you probably need, so there are any number of places where something could have gone off track with one wrong calculation. I would consider trying to refactor some because the source you are trying to emulate did everything with less code. More with less is good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22346/discussion-between-alan-and-dan)

Comment: Thanks Dan I'm learning something here much appreciated! I basicaslly built on the twenty eleven styling for the footer widgets, as i added two additional footer widgets to my own functions.php file in my child theme. When you mean less code, have you any examples? Thanks

Comment: When I say less code, I'm saying that the example you referenced did everything you want to emulate in one class definition (`.footer_col`). If your really trying to do something similar, then you shouldn't need much more than that.

Comment: I see what you mean Dan I have deleted everything apart from #supplementary.five .widget-area{
float: left;
margin-right: 2.9%;
width: 16.7%;
}

#supplementary.five .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area +   .widget-area+ .widget-area{
margin-right: 0;
} I will work with this and start again! Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

First thing off the bat I saw was that this line of code

## site-wrapper{margin: auto; margin: auto; width: 1000px;}

needs to be

## site-wrapper{margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px;}

next thing to try is using whole percentages, browsers dont like fractions and instead they tend to round... try adjust the width to whole numbers whose sum is equal to or less than 100.

Comment: Thanks user1956012 I tried margin: 0 auto; width: 100% but all divs now move when re sized, is there a way to do this like the widget areas on http://www.stylemepretty.com/